# Accessing HDFS after enabling Kerberos security

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I'm using Cloudera 5.2 QuickStart and successfully enabled Kerberos security. MYREALM.COM is my realm

then i created hdfs@MYREALM.COM user using kadmin

I authenticate with command `kinit hdfs` and provided the password. No message appear so look like i got the ticket. Then I ran the simple `hdfs dfs -ls /` command and got the following error:

`ls: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]`

I though i have HDFS super user and now i can access HDFS but it turns out no.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like the **services** have enforced Kerberos auth, but the **clients** still use the old config files with `hadoop.security.authentication=simple`.

Comment: Using Cloudera Manager in quick start and checked the configuration of HDFS.  the property is set to Kerberos

Comment: I have already seen cases where the Manager has *failed* to deploy the client configuration files (even with the Enterprise Edition). Check the **actual** configuration files present on your client node, starting with `/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml`

Comment: i will do this but right now i am trying to resolve a condition in Cloudera Manager     zookeeper service has a error condition saying "Role is missing kerbrose keytab"    I have no idea how to resolve this one. i follow all steps to configure security and and now stuck with these 2 problems

Comment: on surface it look so simple in documentations but when you actually start working with hadoop configurations it becomes nightmare

Comment: Samson,  Cloudera documentation says all configuration files are created in a directory /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process  at run time. is files in /etc/hadoop/conf has any affect ?     what is the location of files when cloudera manager is managing the cluster ?

Comment: The **Cloudera Hadoop services** have their **specific** conf files hidden deep into `/var` but the **clients** use the standard location for Hadoop config files in `/etc`

Comment: Cloudera Manager uses a *database* to manage the "theorical" configuration for all components; then it calls the Agents to check/update the "actual" configuration in *local files*.

Comment: BTW, if the Manager indicates that some configurations are "stale" for specific components on specific nodes, then you can expect bizarre side effects. Check that first. Then go and check the local client conf files on some nodes, to be sure.

Comment: if you run `klist` do you see any tickets?